# HTML Javascript Slideshow Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a very simple HTML and Javascript Slideshow. However, upon initial page load, the page does loads each slide on top of each other. However, when you click the arrow, the slides disappear and the current slide appears and functions regularly.

[The Slide Show before Clicking the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stc6Y.jpg)

[The Slide Show after clicking the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jnp.jpg)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script language="javascript">
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }
        </script>
   </head>

<body>
 <div class="slideshow-container">

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
              <img src="img/hispanic1.png" alt="dancers performing" style="width:100%" >
          <div class="text">Hispanic dancers performing at the Hispanic Heritage Festival</div>
         </div>  

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
              <img src="img/pinkribbon2.png" alt="pink ribbon" style="width:100%">
              <div class="text">Come support Breast Cancer Awareness Month at Santa Fe</div>
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
              <img src="img/bloodbus1.png" alt="Blood Drive Bus" style="width:100%">
              <div class="text">Come donate blood for our Halloween Event!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                 <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                 <img src="img/volunteer1.png" alt="Volunteers Pointing" style="width:100%">
                 <div class="text">Volunteer with a wonderful organization at our Volunteer Fair!</div>
            </div>

             <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                  <img src="img/clubrush1.png" alt="Girls rugby table" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="text">Come out and join a club at Club Rush!</div>
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

         </div>
            <br>

         <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
         </div> 
    </body>
</html>

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Hopefully I was able to format everything correctly. Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated you're code in a runnable snippet. 
Sliding trough slides seems to work there.

Can you check the snippet and see if some code is different?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }
```

```css
img{
  width:100px;

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
              <img src="http://www.acuteaday.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/panda-bear-cub-playing-on-rocking-horse.jpg" alt="dancers performing" >
          <div class="text">Hispanic dancers performing at the Hispanic Heritage Festival</div>
         </div>  

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
              <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/giant-panda-bear-pictures0.jpg" alt="pink ribbon">
              <div class="text">Come support Breast Cancer Awareness Month at Santa Fe</div>
         </div>

         <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
              <img src="http://www.acuteaday.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/panda-bear-cub-playing-on-rocking-horse.jpg" alt="Blood Drive Bus">
              <div class="text">Come donate blood for our Halloween Event!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                 <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                 <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/giant-panda-bear-pictures0.jpg" alt="Volunteers Pointing">
                 <div class="text">Volunteer with a wonderful organization at our Volunteer Fair!</div>
            </div>

             <div class="mySlides fade">
                  <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                  <img src="http://www.acuteaday.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/panda-bear-cub-playing-on-rocking-horse.jpg" alt="Girls rugby table">
                  <div class="text">Come out and join a club at Club Rush!</div>
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

         </div>
            <br>

         <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
         </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. The arrows aren't working and it  it shows each individual image. I'm gonna continue to tinker with it and see if it works.